# How does getmaxyx work? (from curses)

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm confused on how the "function" `getmaxyx` works... because I know it's actually a macro. But how does this macro work?

Code example:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
  int col, row;
  initscr();
  getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's a macro you can see how it works by reading the include file that it is defined in.

Comment: Has to be a macro since the parameters row and col are output data and there is no ptr indicator there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading the `ncurses.h` header file reveals that `getmaxyx` is indeed a macro:

```
#define getmaxyx(win,y,x)       (y = getmaxy(win), x = getmaxx(win))
```

Further investigation shows that `getmaxy` and `getmaxx` are also macros:

```
#define getmaxx(win)            ((win) ? ((win)->_maxx + 1) : ERR)
#define getmaxy(win)            ((win) ? ((win)->_maxy + 1) : ERR)
```

Now, the argument `win` is a pointer to `WINDOW`. In fact, `WINDOW` is a typedef of `struct _win_st`. Perusal of this struct reveals the fields:

```
NCURSES_SIZE_T _maxy, _maxx; /* maximums of x and y, NOT window size */
```

So, when a new window is created, it is associated with a `WINDOW` structure that contains information about the window. In particular, the maximum x and y coordinates of the window are stored in the fields `_maxx` and `_maxy`. These fields are accessed by the macro `getmaxyx()` to provide the window dimensions.